# Magento installation behind load balancer

Tags: magento-1.9

I have magento setup behind a **load balancer** (it is not setup, but all the bits are present). Then I go to my load balancer endpoint and try to install **magento**. It looks like there are errors because, if the load balancer switches the request between nodes, the installation seems to fail (Specifically `local.xml` is not present on one of the node during installation, but it is present in other).

Does anyone know what is the correct way to install magento on a load balanced set of servers. All my media assets are in a shared volume - so I think once the installation phase is complete, the website should work.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to install magento via webgui behind a load balancer? Just install it locally and copy the local.xml, fix the content

Comment: I tried the command line php installer and am hitting strange issues. If I do it via gui (just single node, but behind load balancer), it works - but if I do it via command line, it doesn't seem to work. I am able to login to admin page, but front end doesn't load. If I do a simple wget, it goes into some redirect loop and times out after 20 redirects. Any idea ? I looked around and the urls are correct and I don't have SSL. Something really strange.